# Why I got an Index Error?

Tags: python

```
ant=['1']  
round = 30  

while round:  
    ant += '!'  
    next = []  
    start = 0  

    for current in range(len(ant)):  
        if ant[current] != ant[start]:  
            next.append(str(current-start)+ant[start])  
            start = current  
    ant = "".join(next)  

    round-=1  

print len(ant)
```

I got this source in a blog and tried to run this on 3.2.

(It's about making the ant sequence. `[1,11,12,1121,&c]`

But at line 10, 'IndexError : string index out of range' pops and I hardly understand why.

Comment: If `ant` is a list, why are you doing `ant += '!'`?

Comment: @AbhranilDas that's not a problem... `__iadd__` for lists supports any kind of iterable (e.g. strings)

Comment: Code works fine for me; prints `5808`. Although note that you need to change the last line to `print(len(ant))` for Py 3.2 (it is wirtten for Py2.x).

Comment: Don't name a variable `next` - you are overriding the `next()` builtin. Also, in Python 3.x, `print()` is a function, not a statement, so you need brackets around it's arguments.

Comment: A few solutions for the Look-And-Say sequence can also be found here - http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence

Comment: I still don't know why but after accept your advice, It works.

Comment: Maybe somethings wrong in my computer..Thank u guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is run fine on my computer. My python version is 2.7

the `len(ant)` is 5808

But I think you python code is not very clear and not pythonic. You can read this [link](http://www.siafoo.net/article/52) and [this](http://www.cafepy.com/article/be_pythonic/)

for example, use this

```
for index, x in enumerate(ant):
```

instead of `for current in range(len(ant)):`

And don't use `ant +='!'`. It should be `ant.append('!')`

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Your code [runs fine for me](http://ideone.com/chUd5).

---

test.py:

```
ant=['1']
round = 30

while round:
    ant += '!'
    next = []
    start = 0

    for current in range(len(ant)):
        if ant[current] != ant[start]:
            next.append(str(current-start)+ant[start])
            start = current
    ant = "".join(next)

    round-=1

print len(ant)
```

---

```
$ python test.py
5808
```

Comment: [Works fine in Python 3 as well.](http://ideone.com/3yn0s) - aside from needing to change `print len(ant)` to `print(len(ant))` for Python3 style print-as-function.